What is valid or invalid, or sound or unsound, about this argument that an unfalsifiable theory is a true theory?
Statement. An unfalsifiable theory is automatically a true theory.
Proof. Forward direction. Let this theory be unfalsifiable. Then an intelligent man can adopt it and use it indefinitely. Therefore it is as a matter of fact true.
Backward direction. Let this theory be true. Because truth is eternal by nature, therefore it is unfalsifiable.
Therefore every unfalsifiable theory is automatically a true theory. Q.E.D..
What is valid/invalid or sound/unsound about this argument?

@Rushi. Eternality is a property of Truth. Therefore any prediction of a true theory that is true in the present, will be true in the future. Therefore it is unfalsifiable too.

@KristianBerry an intelligent man's perpetual usage is equivalent to factually holding by the definition of the prepositional phrase "matter of fact".

Both directions are invalid. An intelligent man  needs good reasons to use something "perpetually", and to be able to use it in the first place. That some unfalsifiable theory, like existence of undetectable pink unicorns, say, can be "used" at all is rather doubtful. And one can use something perpetually while explicitly denying that it is "as matter of fact" true. We continue to use Newtonian mechanics even though we know that it is not, in fact, true. It is simply good enough for many practical purposes. True and useful are plainly distinct concepts, and so are eternal and unfalsifiable.

The theory that the Earth is flat is a true theory, i.e. it is a real theory, even though it is wrong.

@ChrisDegnen "The theory that the Earth is flat is a true theory, i.e. it is a real theory, even though it is wrong." A real theory may be true or false, so "true theory" cannot be synonymous with "real theory". If there is such a thing as the Flat Earth Theory, then it is ipso facto a real theory, and theories are either true or false if they are about anything at all. The Flat Earth Theory is clearly about the Earth, so it must be either true or false. Strictly speaking, theories are not correct or wrong. People are, depending on whether they support a true or a false theory.

@Speakpigeon I am referring to truth as Aletheia, i.e. as disclosure, where the truth of a matter is simply what is disclosed. This avoids issues of falsifiability. In contrast, the "characterization of truth as 'agreement', adaequatio, όμοίωσις, is very general and empty." GA2 215.  … "To say that an assertion "is true" signifies that it uncovers the entity as it is in itself. Such an assertion asserts, points out, 'lets' the entity 'be seen' (ἀπόφανσις) in its uncoveredness. …

(continues) "… The Being-true (truth) of the assertion must be understood as Being-uncovering. Thus truth has by no means the structure of an agreement between knowing and the object in the sense of a likening of one entity (the subject) to another (the Object)." GA2 218. In this way a true theory or a true thing is just what it appears as. But I admit I'm playing with the general meaning of the question by digging into the root meaning of truth because 'agreement' and falsifiability confuse the issue of what truth is.

Really, an unfalsifiable theory isn't a theory at all. A scientific theory has to be able to be put to some kind of test to qualify as a theory. Otherwise it's just a statement like "Trees are nice."

@ChrisDegnen "the root meaning of truth" This is not the root meaning of truth. Yours is distinct from the common notion of truth. - 2. "meaning of truth" Truth does not have a meaning. It is the word "truth" which does. And the word "truth" just means truth. - 3. "This avoids issues of falsifiability." There is no problem with the common notion of truth and falsifiability. - 4. "truth as 'agreement" Truth is not an agreement (between people). - 5. "* "To say that an assertion "is true" signifies that it uncovers the entity as it is in itself.*"  This is not what it signifies.

@Speakpigeon I will try to develop this further, but for now I will just say that Heidegger's idea of truth is not a correspondence theory, matching ideas to reality. It's about how we relate to and understand the world, e.g. " 'Being-true' ("truth") means Being-uncovering. ... By such drastic ways of defining this concept we may succeed in eliminating the idea of agreement from the conception of truth. Must we not pay for this dubious gain by plunging the 'good' old tradition into nullity?" This page continues at GA2 219

@Speakpigeon The above Wikipedia link on Aletheia mentions Heidegger's late (1968) reversal on ἀλήθεια as 'truth' as discussed on Enowning blog. I have seen mention that one of Heidegger's aims is to dissolve notions of being & truth to the point that we can know that we cannot know. E.g. "Does not the actuality of knowing and judging get broken asunder into two ways of Being—two 'levels' which can never be pieced together . . . ?" GA2 217


What is valid/invalid or sound/unsound about this argument?

It's quite simple really:

Proof. Forward direction. Let this theory be unfalsifiable. Then an intelligent man can adopt it and use it indefinitely. Therefore it is as a matter of fact true.

This is a non-sequitur, for a theory to be "unfalsifiable" it would mean that there are no predictions of the theory that could ever possibly be observed to be false.
This means the theory makes no useful predictions about the future, meaning it predicts ANY possible states of affairs in the future no matter what.  It is therefore quite impossible to USE regardless of if the theory is in fact true.
The usefulness of a falsifiable theory comes from it making predictions about the world that expand our understanding by making non obvious predictions that coincide with the theory's explanatory power.
An unfalsifiable theory explains nothing because it explains every possible state of affairs.
Your conclusion is also a non-sequitur based on a base assertion of truth.
